# My View's doesn't exist after moving it to hosting site

Tags: php, laravel

After I've moved it to my production server my views began to not exist and thats odd.

here is my stack trace

```
Unhandled Exception
Message:
View [employer.jds] doesn't exist.
Location:
/var/www/vhosts/aquariusmc.com/httpdocs/laravel/view.php on line 170
Stack Trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/aquariusmc.com/httpdocs/laravel/view.php(107): Laravel\View->path('employer.jds')
#1 /var/www/vhosts/aquariusmc.com/httpdocs/laravel/view.php(218): Laravel\View->__construct('employer.jds', Array)
#2 /var/www/vhosts/aquariusmc.com/httpdocs/application/controllers/employer/main.php(18): Laravel\View::make('employer.jds', Array)
#3 [internal function]: Employer_Main_Controller->get_jobDispatchSheet()
#4 /var/www/vhosts/aquariusmc.com/httpdocs/laravel/routing/controller.php(325): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#5 /var/www/vhosts/aquariusmc.com/httpdocs/laravel/routing/controller.php(285): Laravel\Routing\Controller->response('jobdispatchshee...', Array)
#6 /var/www/vhosts/aquariusmc.com/httpdocs/laravel/routing/controller.php(165): Laravel\Routing\Controller->execute('jobdispatchshee...', Array)
#7 /var/www/vhosts/aquariusmc.com/httpdocs/laravel/routing/route.php(153): Laravel\Routing\Controller::call('employer.main@j...', Array)
#8 /var/www/vhosts/aquariusmc.com/httpdocs/laravel/routing/route.php(124): Laravel\Routing\Route->response()
#9 /var/www/vhosts/aquariusmc.com/httpdocs/laravel/laravel.php(167): Laravel\Routing\Route->call()
#10 /var/www/vhosts/aquariusmc.com/httpdocs/public/index.php(34): require('/var/www/vhosts...')
#11 {main}
```

Comment: Try with `realpath('employer.jds')` then the error message should show you the full path which is more easy to trouble-shoot.

Comment: Are you definitely sure they were uploaded?

Comment: m8r-1jmw5r: i'll try it

Comment: Oddman: hi, I upload the whole folder to my server. so I'm sure they were all uploaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by using lowercase on all of my view's filename. I think Plesk(CentOS) has something to do with the camelCase filename. but anyway thanks!

Comment: This is a very common error when developing on windows, but using a linux production machine. Just avoid upper case all together in filenames. Linux is case sensitive, Windows is not (in most cases, although NTFS supports it)